# Core Data: Illegal attempt to establish a relationship 'statusmedia' between objects in different contexts

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I am using Core Data on my app. After a light weight migration and code upgradation to swift 4.0, I am facing few issues.

**Issue 1**

**Mutating a managed object 0x7fd0881de320  (0x7fd0884589b0) after it has been removed from its context.**

**Issue 2**

**Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Illegal attempt to establish a relationship 'statusmedia' between objects in different contexts (source =  (entity: Status; id: 0x10f6dc280**

Termination issue is very serious.

> Note that I have used only one Context (default one and not private)

*Let me know if you want more information from me...*

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many may happen unfortunately to lead to this but top candidates to check would be:

1. In your model there are delete rules on relations. A "cascade" option should delete the object(s) in relation when deleting this object. If this is not expected such an error could easily be produced.
2. You are deleting an object but then still use it. It is a logical bug but can be easily confirmed by marking deleted managed objects (put the IDs of deleted objects into some array) and then checking if the failed object is marked (it's ID exists in that array).
3. You are using multiple contexts but not aware of it. Some tools like fetch result controllers are potential candidates.

There are still other possibilities but I would start with these mentioned to begin with.

Comment: Thank you @Matic Oblak, I am trying the above steps and will let you know, if this solved my problem.